# Slope shows strange grid texture

Tags: arcmap, slope, texture

Being aware that there were already similar questions concerning the output of hillshade/slope layer with an unwanted grid texture, but still I m confused, so I hope someone can explain it.
Working with ArcMap 10.7. / QGIS (Madeira), I made a SLOPE layer out of a DEM ( cell size 1x1 m) and got a slope raster with a grid texture [image: slope 1x1m with grid tecture], which I don't want because I need to do further analyses with MAXENt.
What could be the reason for such texture and how can I eliminate it?

Comment: This is a commonly observed issue, the raster was re-projected or resampled using nearest neighbor. Go back to the source data and reprocess using bilinear resampling for whatever operation was applied, I suspect that it was re-projected as this is the most common place these linear artifacts are introduced but, any processing that uses resampling can introduce this effect. If that is not it, I do have another idea regarding ESRI index tiling.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Originally, there were two DGM-layer in different projections, which first I projected into the same CS and then combined them into one DGM-Layer using the Mosaic Raster- function in ArcGiS. So, yes, I projected them first into the same CS. I prefer to work on this combined Layer as it reflects the total area I m working with. Do you think, this can be the problem? What do you mean by bilinear resampling exactly?

Comment: If you bring up the project tool you will see that there is a resampling method option, which defaults to nearest neighbor. For continuous data, such as a DEM, this needs to be changed to bilinear or cubic. Also, if you are using on-the-fly projection during raster operations, the default resampling globally is nearest but, can be changed somewhere in the global settings.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! It worked!!:)

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, if this is not answered elsewhere, can you please compile your comments as an answer?